# Gradle 4.2.+ Could not resolve navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

After upgrading Android Studio to Fox version, Gradle from `4.1.3` to `7.0.0` or even `4.2.+`, and `distributionUrl` to `gradle-7.0.1-bin.zip`,  I couldn’t build my app anymore.

This is the error log:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':onboarding:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebugMobDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':onboarding:debugMobDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5.
     Required by:
         project :onboarding
      > Skipped due to earlier error
```

It seems Gradle couldn't download NavigationKTX version 2.3.5.
The solution is downgrading but
**How to fix the issue without downgrading to Gradle version 4.1.+**

I wanna use jetpack compose in my application so I need to update gradle to 4.2.+.

Comment: I'd start by looking at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html

It appears to be a simple dependency resolution issue.  perhaps you should show your build.gradle where your dependencies are defined.

Comment: @CalvinTaylor No it's not, because it's working with Gradle version 4.2.2, It's exactly because of upgrade

Comment: I didn't come here to argue.  Did you run gradle help --warning-mode=all before upgrading?

Comment: > Task :onboarding:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebugMobDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':onboarding:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebugMobDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':onboarding:debugMobDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5.
     Required by:
         project :onboarding

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5.

Comment: switch your gradle back to 4.2.2 temporarily, then run  gradle help --warning-mode=all

Comment: if possible, I think you should migrate `android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5` to `androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx` . `androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx`  working well for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current Gradle version for Arctic Fox is eg. `gradle-7.1.1-all.zip` (or `bin`).

AGP & SafeArgs:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        // classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.0-alpha02"
    }
}


...
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

---

And the whole `android.arch` name-space had been superseded:

```
android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5
```

Use the current [`androidx`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation) name-space instead, where `2.3.5` is the latest stable version:

```
androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5 / 2.4.0-alpha06
```

Be aware not to mix up these library name-spaces (there may be further conflicts) - or that enabling the Jetifier may be required, depending on further outdated dependencies (because name-space `com.android.support` had also been superseded by `androidx`). Unless a) updating the dependencies and b) fixing all imports ...this project won't build.

Comment: Note that there are a *ton* of fixes and improvements in Navigation 2.4 for `navigation-ui-ktx` and `navigation-fragment-ktx` users.

Comment: @ianhanniballake This also counts for Navigation Safe-Args plugin, eg. when upgrading from AGP 4.2 to 7.0. Have seen your answer just yesterday.